# setInterval with delay on first time run

Tags: timer, delay, settimeout

I need to create delay for first time setInterval() function when page/window load. How to make it?

Consider that I have a slider with setInterval() showing images, but in first start slider I need to show to user a shor preload animation about 7 sec. So, I need to force slider to wait starting timer before into plays.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(setInterval(),7000);
```

setTimeout calls the function setInterval after 1000ms i.e 1 sec

Hope i helped you